# Error creating an image format with an unknown type

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller, ios10

While choosing an image from the image picker in iOS 10, I am getting an error - Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error

Here is my code:

```
func CamaraInit(){

    let isOk = UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera)

    if isOk {

        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imagePicker.cameraDevice = .rear
        imagePicker.showsCameraControls = true
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
        // imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .video
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
func imageInit(){

    let isOk = UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary)

    if isOk {

        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self

        //imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    var useImage : UIImage!

    let originalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage

    if editedImage == nil {
        useImage = originalImage
    } else {
        useImage = editedImage
    }

    if picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(useImage, nil, nil, nil)
    }

    self.UIPhotoImage = useImage

    self.viewChange()

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I have searched a lot of materials but still have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

seems it is kind of warning not error,at least in my case...after uploading your image,viewWillApear will be automatically called again.
thats why you think image was not uploaded.